# How to save timestamp field in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The serializer.py file

```
class TabsionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Tabsion
        fields = ('sen_id','det_id','latitude','longitude','start_or_end','user_id','username','type','timestamp')
```

In the above the timestamp field is automatically set by database and type field is set by default to one. So these fields were not added to the database.

View.py

```
class StartReportSave(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        reqData  = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        savData  = {}
        savData['sen_d'] = reqData['data']['section']['id'];
        savData['det_id'] = reqData['data']['depot']['id'];
        savData['latitude'] = reqData['data']['locationData']['latitude'];
        savData['longitude'] = reqData['data']['locationData']['longitude'];
        savData['start_or_end'] = reqData['data']['start_or_end'] ;
        savData['username']= reqData['userData'][0]['username'];
        savData['user_id']= reqData['userData'][0]['id'];   
        serializer = TabsionSerializer(data=savData)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data,status=201))

        return JsonResponse(savData,safe=False)
```

model.py

```
class Tabsion(models.Model):
    sen_id = models.IntegerField()
    det_id = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_or_end = models.IntegerField()
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    type = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tab_reporting_session'
```

When I try to add data the error shows up

> Timestamp , Type field are required

How can I resolve this?

What will be the correct way to fetch the id of this inserted record and also add it to another log table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use read only field

   ```
   class TabsionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = Tabsion
           fields = ('sen_id','det_id','latitude','longitude','start_or_end','user_id','username','type','timestamp')
           read_only_fields = ('type','timestamp')
   ```
2. The save_data consist of the id required.

   ```
   save_data = serializer.save(data=data)

   instance_id = save_data.id`
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
class TabsionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
    model = Tabsion
    fields = ('sen_id','det_id','latitude','longitude','start_or_end','user_id','username','type','timestamp')
    extra_kwargs = {'type': {'read_only': True, 'required': False}, 'timestamp': {'read_only': True, 'required': False}}
```

> Setting read_only=True in extra_kwargs will do the trick for you.

Read more: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments

> Or you can use read_only_fields

```
class TabsionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tabsion
        fields = ('sen_id','det_id','latitude','longitude','start_or_end','user_id','username','type','timestamp')
        read_only_fields = ('type','timestamp')
```

Read more: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields

> The second solution is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can set auto now for timestamp field in Tabsion model

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```